# C# Handle Web services Exception 401

Tags: c#, web-services, exception, http-status-code-401

I am trying to invoke the `Webservices` in `C#` using Visual Studio 2017 generated Proxy classes as shown below. But we want to `catch` `Webservices` exception mainly HTTP 401, please let us know how to do it.

The exception does not get caught in regular try catch block.

```
clientpo = new POOBJ.GenerateBill_OutClient(myBinding, ea);
clientpo.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxx";
clientpo.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "yyy";
clientpo.Open();                                
clientpo.GenerateBill_OutAsync(objmateira);
clientpo.Close();
```

Comment: Are you handling WebException? Update the question with exception handling code of yours

Comment: We are handling General Exception by placing the above code using Simple Try Catch.  Can you please let us know how to get the Web Exception from the Proxy classes.

Comment: You need to provide source code that will help us understand better about your problems. BTW, I already mentioned you need to handle WebException

Comment: Source code is already put above in main description